# Почему std::forward замедляет код при работе с универсальной ссылкой, которой передаётся rvalue?

Tags: c++, оптимизация, шаблоны-с++, производительность, rvalue

Есть две функции, работающие с универсальными ссылками. Одна из них позволяет производить копирование, другая нет:

```
template<class T>
void Foo2(T&& a) {
    string b = std::forward<T>(a);
};

template<class T>
void Foo3(T&& a) {
    string b = a;
};
```

С выключенной оптимизацией при вызове `Foo2` и `Foo3` с rvalue, `Foo2` работает всегда медленнее, чем `Foo3`. Откуда берутся накладные расходы, если `std::forward<T>` - это приведение времени компиляции? Пробовал и на GCC, и на компиляторе Microsoft.

Код которым я тестировал:

```
const int tryes = 1'000'000;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    {
        muTimer T1;
        T1.start();
        for (int i = 0; i < tryes; i++) {
            Foo3(std::move("Habrahabr"));
        }
        cout << T1.stop().duration() << endl;;
    }
    {
        muTimer T1;
        T1.start();
        for (int i = 0; i < tryes; i++) {
            Foo2(std::move("Habrahabr"));
        }
        cout << T1.stop().duration() << endl;;
    }
    {
        muTimer T1;
        T1.start();
        for (int i = 0; i < tryes; i++) {
            Foo3(std::move("Habrahabr"));
        }
        cout << T1.stop().duration() << endl;;
    }
    {
        muTimer T1;
        T1.start();
        for (int i = 0; i < tryes; i++) {
            Foo2(std::move("Habrahabr"));
        }
        cout << T1.stop().duration() << endl;;
    }
}
```

Comment: А можно пример как тестировали.

Comment: @ffk добавил код.

Comment: На будущее: нет никакого смысла пытаться анализировать производительность на отладочной сборке.

Comment: На всякий случай поясню, что `std::move("Habrahabr")` не имеет смысла потому что литерал `"Habrahabr"` имеет тип `char [10]` а не `std::string`.

Comment: `std::forward` это не приведение времени компиляции, а функция, так же как и `std::move`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по ассемблеру, сгенерированному VC++, он при отсутствии оптимизации (`/Od`) просто не инлайнит сам `forward`, делая этот шаблон функцией, вызываемой через `call` - вот и получается то, что получается...

В результате в `Foo2` добавляется код

```
call    ??$forward@AEAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_trait...........
```

что и приводит к замедлению, несмотря на то, что там почти что пусто -

```
??$forward@AEAV?$basic_string@DU..... PROC  
    mov QWORD PTR [rsp+8], rcx
    mov rax, QWORD PTR _Arg$[rsp]
    ret 0
```

Ну, а `call` всегда очень плохо влияет на производительность...

При оптимизации ассемблерный код по сути одинаков.